# Fragment application displaying 2 instances of the same fragment in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-studio

I am writing a simple app that displays a fragment in the main activity.  When I run the app, it displays two instances of the fragment on the screen.  I have included the code below.  By the way, when I remove `FT.commit();` from the main activity class, only one fragment instance is displayed on the screen as it should.  What is the problem here?

thanks.

**Fragment layout XML file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**Fragment Class**

```
    package com.example.fragment;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class fragmentone extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragoner, container, false);
    }
}
```

**Main activity layout XML file:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

<fragment
    android:name="com.example.fragment.fragmentone"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/fragone"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragoner">


    </fragment>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Main Activity Class**

```
    package com.example.fragment;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction FT = manager.beginTransaction();

        fragmentone Fone = new fragmentone();

        FT.add(R.id.fragone,Fone);
        FT.commit();


    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the problem here?

If you use the `<fragment>` tag, do not **also** use a `FragmentTransaction` to add the same fragment. Those are two separate techniques and should not be mixed.

Simply get rid of every line from `onCreate()` except the call to `super.onCreate()` and the `setContentView()` call, and stick with your static `<fragment>`.

Comment: Can you explain a little more about why you shouldn't mix using the `<fragment>` tag and `FragmentTransaction`?

Comment: @David: `<fragment>` is for static fragments, ones that will always be there. The code in the question will wind up creating two overalapping instances of `fragmentone`: the one from `<fragment>` and the one from `FragmentTransaction`. In Jetpack-based Android app development, you use `<fragment>` for your `NavHostFragment` and let it handle the work to display all your other fragments.

Answer (score 0):

Either remove the  from your activity's layout view or stop using commit. You can use a  as a container for your fragment. Add an id to your FrameLayout than use: 

`FragmentManger manager=getFragmentManager();
Fragment fragment=manager.findFragmentById(R.id.frameContainer);`